# How does HtmlNodeNavigator work?

Tags: html-agility-pack

How to achieve

```
XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument("books.xml");
XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator nodeset = navigator.Select(xpath);

while (nodeset.MoveNext())
{
    // Clone iterator here when working with it.
    Do something
}
```

in html agility pack? There is not much documentation. I have searched through the web. I can't get a piece of sample. There is no HtmlPathNodeIterator. HtmlNodeNavigator navigator = Html.CreateNavigator() doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to select nodes is ... to not use the navigator, and instead use the HtmlNode SelectNodes and SelectSingleNodes methods. Like this:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("books.html");
foreach(HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(xpath))
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: it's a sound solution, but after one change, all nodes will become null pointers. how can I avoid that?

Comment: what do you mean? if SelectsNodes returns a null, it means there is no node that match the xpath expression?

Comment: I mean I can only read the selected nodes. But you cannot do any manipulations. ie. You can't delete any nodes, move any nodes. If you do so, all other node selected nodes will become null